# Bind object to ConverterParameter fails with XamlParseException in WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

## Initial situation

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app where I have a model that contains several properties as shown below (just an excerpt of 3 properties, it has a lot more).

```
public class WorkUnit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime? To
    {
        get { return Get<DateTime?>(); }
        set
        {
            Set(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("To");
            OnPropertyChanged("ToAsShortTimeString");
        }
    }
    public string ToAsShortTimeString
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (To.HasValue)
            {
                if (Type == WorkUnitType.StartEnd)
                    return To.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);

                var duration = To.Value - From;
                return DateHelper.FormatTime(duration, false);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
    public short? Type
    {
        get { return Get<short?>(); }
        set 
        { 
            Set(value); 
            OnPropertyChanged("Type");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using MVVMLight. There are several work units in an ObservableCollection that is bound to a list box on a Windows Phone page. The collection itself is part of a (WorkDay) view model which in turn is bound to the page itself.

## What I want to do

I have a lot of properties in my model that are just used to format some properties for the UI. One such is ToAsShortTimeString which returns the time given by the *To* property, depending on the *Type* and the *From* properties, formatted as string.

In order to clean up my model I want to remove such formatter-properties as much as possible and use converters (IValueConverter) as much as possible. One further reason to move away from such properties is that the database that I use (iBoxDB) doesn't have member attributes like [Ignore] that is available for SQLite. So all properties with supported types are stored in the database. However, such formatter properties shouldn't be stored if possible.

## What I did - 1st try

I now transformed all properties to converters and most of the time this was no problem. However, *ToAsShortTimeString* not just uses one property but 3 to format the input. Therefore, in XAML I need to provide either those 3 properties to the value converter or the work unit itself which is bound to the page.

```
public class WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var workUnit = (WorkUnit) value;
        if (workUnit.To.HasValue)
        {
            if (workUnit.Type == WorkUnitType.StartEnd)
                return workUnit.To.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);

            var duration = workUnit.To.Value - workUnit.From;
            return DateHelper.FormatTime(duration, false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So I changed the binding of the *Text* property in the TextBlock that shows the formatted *To* property to the WorkUnit that is bound to the page.

```
<TextBlock 
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Text="{Binding WorkUnit,Converter={StaticResource WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter}}" 
    FontSize="28" 
    FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource TsColorWhite}"/>
```

Unfortunately, when the *To* property changes in the model, even though OnPropertyChanged is called (see model code above), the text block doesn't get updated. I assume the reason is that only those controls are updated where some property is directly bound to the changed model property.

## What I did - 2nd try

So as I need 3 properties from WorkUnit in order to correctly format *To* I changed the binding as follows. I bound *Text* to *WorkUnit.To* and set the *ConverterParameter* to the WorkUnit itself. With this change I hoped that whenever *To* is changed in the model and the value converter is called, I can format the time because I have all the info provided from the converter parameter (WorkUnit). (I'm not printing the updated converter here but I changed it to accomodate the change on the value and parameter input parameters)

```
<TextBlock 
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Text="{Binding WorkUnit.To,Converter={StaticResource WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter},ConverterParameter={Binding WorkUnit}}" 
    FontSize="28" 
    FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource TsColorWhite}"/>
```

Unfortunately, in this case a XamlParseException exception is thrown.

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.ConverterParameter'. [Line: 61 Position: 18] ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.TryApplyMarkupExtensionValue(Object target, XamlPropertyToken propertyToken, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)}
```

## Question

So is there a way to remove the formatter-property from my model so that I can keep my model as clean as possible? Is there sth. wrong with my converter? Is there any other way that I currently don't know of?

Comment: Have you defined your converter as a static resource in Xaml?

Comment: @NateDiamond Yes. The converter itself works when I don't provide the ConverterParameter. It just doesn't get updated then.

Comment: Ah, just saw that part at the end. `ConverterParameter`s can't be set via binding. What you need to do is have your `WorkUnit` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise a `PropertyChanged` event on each property value set.

Comment: Yep, doing this already :) I updated the code above to reflect that. The point is the the Text property of the TextBlock does not bind to one of the properties To or Type but rather binds to the WorkUnit which is the datacontext of the page actually. So WorkUnit will not change when the To property changes and therefore the TextBlock is not updated. But I cannot bind to WorkUnit.To because I need WorkUnit.Type in the converter to make the correct conversion.

Comment: Why don't you expose a string property in your WorkUnit class and just bind straight to that? No converters, no mess converter parameters, just a straightforward string property?

Comment: Candidate for Multibinding, maybe? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe. But unfortunately not supported on Windows Phone (neither Universal nor Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a property in your `WorkUnit` called `EndTimeString`

```
public string EndTimeString
{
    get
    { 
        string endTime = null;

        if (this.To.HasValue)
        {
            if (this.Type == WorkUnitType.StartEnd)
            {
                endTime = this.To.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
            }
            else
            {
                var duration = this.To.Value - this.From;
                endTime = DateHelper.FormatTime(duration, false);
            }        
        }

        return endTime
    }
}
```

Of course, if `To` value changes, you want to notify the UI that the `EndTimeString` has also changed so that it picks up the new value:

```
public DateTime? To
{
    get { return Get<DateTime?>(); }
    set
    {
        Set(value);
        OnPropertyChanged("To");
        OnPropertyChanged("EndTimeString");
    }
}
```

And then just bind straight to that string:

```
...Text="{Binding WorkUnit.EndTimeString}" />
```

Comment: This'll definitely work. I should have mentioned in my question that I had such property before but wanted to go away and use converters instead. I had a lot of such properties that were actually not really part of my model but just used to do some formatting or calculation for the UI. In order to clean up my model I removed all of those formatting/calculation properties and converted them to converters. Maybe in this case this is the only/best solution(?).

Comment: @Stephan Yeah, it would've helped if you mentioned that :) What is the parent of your WorkUnit (WU) object? Is that in an ObservableCollection of WU objects? Or is it a single WU object in your ViewModel?

Comment: I updated the question so that it hopefully explains the whole scenario better

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't bind to parameters.

This would be easy with `MultiBinding` but that's not available for Windows Phone (as you stated in your comment).

You could implement it yourself but if you are not really into it :), there are implementations trying to mimic this behaviour. One of them can be found from [the joy of code](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx).

There is a NuGet package called [Krempel's WP7 Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krempel.WP7) which has above implemented for WP7 but it works on WP8.x as well.

Downside is that it can only bind to elements in visual tree, so you have to use (for lack of a better word) relaying UI elements to get the job done. I have used similar technique myself when I can't bind directly to a property I need to. One case is `AppBar`, you can't bind directly to enabled property, so instead I use something like

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="{Binding AppBarEnabled}" 
          IsEnabledChanged="ToggleAppBar" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

Anyway, below is full example, without any groovy patterns, on how you can achieve multibinding using above library. Try it out and see if it's worth the trouble. Options are that you have "extra" properties in your model or some extra elements and complexity in your view.

I used your WorkUnit model and Converter to make it more useful and easier to understand.

Outcome should be something like this.

[image]

---

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="WP8MultiBinding.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Krempel.WP7.Core.Controls;assembly=Krempel.WP7.Core"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WP8MultiBinding"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <conv:WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter 
              x:Key="WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter" />
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Multibinding & converter -->
        <controls:MultiBinding 
            x:Name="MultiBinding" 
            Converter="{StaticResource WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter}"
            NumberOfInputs="3"
            Input1="{Binding ElementName=Type, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Input2="{Binding ElementName=From, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Input3="{Binding ElementName=To, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <!-- Output from multibinded conversion -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MultiBinding, Path=Output}" Grid.Row="0" />
        <!-- Update WorkUnit properties -->
        <Button Click="UpdateButtonClick" Grid.Row="1">Test MultiBinding</Button>

        <!-- Helper elements, might want to set visibility to collapsed -->
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Type" Text="{Binding WorkUnit.Type, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="From" Text="{Binding WorkUnit.From, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="To" Text="{Binding WorkUnit.To, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>    
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace WP8MultiBinding
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WorkUnit = new WorkUnit()
                {
                    To = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5),
                    From = DateTime.Now,
                    Type = WorkUnitType.StartEnd
                };
        }

        public WorkUnit WorkUnit { get; set; }

        // Ensure bindings do update
        private void UpdateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkUnit.Type = WorkUnit.Type == WorkUnitType.StartEnd ? 
                            WorkUnit.Type = WorkUnitType.Other : 
                            WorkUnit.Type = WorkUnitType.StartEnd;

            WorkUnit.From = WorkUnit.From.AddMinutes(60);
            if (WorkUnit.To.HasValue)
                WorkUnit.To = WorkUnit.To.Value.AddMinutes(30);
        }
    }

    public enum WorkUnitType
    {
        StartEnd,
        Other
    }

    public class WorkUnit : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private WorkUnitType _type;
        private DateTime _from;
        private DateTime? _to;

        public WorkUnitType Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public DateTime From
        {
            get { return _from; }
            set { _from = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public DateTime? To
        {
            get { return _to; }
            set { _to = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // Multivalue Converter
    public class WorkUnitToEndTimeStringConverter : Krempel.WP7.Core.Controls.IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private const string DateFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Index: 0 = Type, 1 = From, 2 = To
            if (values[2] != null)
            {
                var type = (WorkUnitType) Enum.Parse(typeof (WorkUnitType), values[0].ToString());
                var from = DateTime.ParseExact(values[1].ToString(), DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var to = DateTime.ParseExact(values[2].ToString(), DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                if (type == WorkUnitType.StartEnd)
                    return to.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);

                var duration = to - from;
                return duration; // DateHelper.FormatTime(duration, false);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```